# Converting UIImage to Stream

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, stream, uiimage

i am using buddy sdk

this sample tells me how to add profile picture, i try with every way but when i try to use this code

```
client.CreateUserAsync("username","password").ContinueWith(r => { var user = r.Result;

// upload a profile photo
Stream photoStream = GetSomePhoto();
user.AddProfilePhotoAsync(photoStream);
});
```

This is my Code, but it gives me over array problem

```
    var img = loginImagePicker.Image.AsPNG().AsStream(); 
    var hu = await user.AddProfilePhotoAsync(img);
```

this is the problem

[image]

any advice?

Comment: Can you add a description of the error you get ? e.g. compile, runtime exception ?

Comment: sure i just uploded the picture,

Comment: the fact is,
i just try to upload stream file but returns me "too much character size" strange

http://buddy.com/dotnetsdk/html/M_Buddy_AuthenticatedUser_AddProfilePhotoAsync_1.htm

this is the link of sdk

Comment: infact i just used your stream converter ( wich saw your posts ) like aspng().asstream, its goes but throw that thing

Answer (score 6):

From your screenshot it seems you issue is **not** getting the stream, i.e

```
var img = loginImagePicker.Image.AsPNG().AsStream();
```

the above line seems to work. The problem is that your SDK, the next call, i.e.:

```
var hu = await user.AddProfilePhotoAsync(img);
```

tries to encode something (likely the image) into an URI (see [source](https://github.com/BuddyPlatform/Buddy-DotNet-SDK/blob/master/src/BuddyServiceClient/BuddyServiceClientHttp.cs#L280)).

There's a limit on the size of an URI (the exception you're getting) so it's either because there's some bug (URI type or Buddy SDK) or there's a limit on the image size you can provide.

In any case the issue is not related to converting the `UIImage` to `Stream`, that part works - the problem is what's done on the `Stream` later.

Comment: i guess its a bug than, do you have any other advcie? if you get close to buddy framework, there is not Service sub framework too sadly by the way you are rocks, i see you whole monotouch topics at here thanks for support hero :)

Comment: http://buddy.com/developers/#Pictures_ProfilePhoto_Add check windows phone 8 sdk, possible to port monotouch?

Comment: Using your link I only see a menu (on the left side) and an empty space (no code or anything but a slight blue gradient background) on both Safari and Chrome (OSX).

Comment: sorry me, http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/14232/anyone-convert-this-wp8-code-to-monotouch#latest check this, http://buddy.com/developers/ i send you fisrt  link is under pictures , add profile picture wich i open topic at xamarin hq